# typescript fazer com que alguma prop seja instancia de componente react

Tags: react, typescript, interface

considerando o código seguinte:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

interface PropsInterface {
  onTop?: Node; //ou coisa equivalente
  onBody?: JSX.Element;
}

export class Node extends Component<PropsInterface> {
  render() {
    console.log(this instanceof Node);

    const { onTop = <>onTop</>, onBody = <>onBody</> } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <div>{onTop}</div>
        <div>{onBody}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```

Ali na possivel linha 4 tem um erro, é sobre ele que eu quero perguntar,
como eu parametrizo para dizer que onTop, caso seja declarado ele precisa ser uma instancia de Node? Ignorem que isso talvez gere um loop infinito, ex:

```
...
<Node onTop={<Node />} onBody={<p>jsx qualquer<p>}/>
...
```

Sem typescript era simples, bastava eu fazer uma verificação como na possível linha 10, mas como se faz isso lá na seçao interface?

Editado para complementar a resposta da pergunta de @Andre:

Eu já tinha tentado essa sugestão antes de postar a pergunta inicial.
Usando 'Node' como parâmetro, tenho o seguinte erro:

> Nenhuma sobrecarga corresponde a esta chamada.   A sobrecarga 1 de 2,
> '(props: PropsInterface | Readonly): Node', gerou o
> seguinte erro:
>
> O tipo 'ReactElement<any, any>' não tem as propriedades a seguir do tipo 'Node': render, context, setState, forceUpdate e mais 2.   A
> sobrecarga 2 de 2, '(props: PropsInterface, context: any): Node',
> gerou o seguinte erro.
> O tipo 'Element' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'Node'.

Comment: A menos que eu tenha entendido errado, é só declarar `onTop?: Node`. O problema é que a sintaxe que você usou para declarar a classe não está sendo reconhecida, escreva como `class Node` ao invés de `Node = class`.

Comment: @Andre Obrigado pelas observações.
Eu editei a minha pergunta inicial, acrescentando o erro que recebo quando usei a opção 'Node'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você pressupõe que o tipo de `<Component>` é `Component`, mas não, lembre-se que o JSX não existe em tempo de execução, há um processo de build que transforma esse código em algo semelhante a `React.createElement(Component, {})`, apesar de a classe ser instanciada no processo de criação e montagem do componente, não é a instância dela que é retornada

Se você precisa renderizar um componente específico dentro de outro mas com propriedades variáveis, basta permitir passar apenas as propriedades do componente filho no componente pai em vez do componente inteiro, o funcionamento é semelhante ao encaminhamento de refs:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <Child {...this.props.childProps} />
  }

}

class Child extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return this.props.content;
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Parent childProps={{ content: 'Exemplo 1' }} />
    <br />
    <Parent childProps={{ content: 'Exemplo 2' }} />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Creio que seja o ReactNode que você queira usar:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
```

Comment: Não creio que seja o caso de importar mais uma biblioteca, no caso da minha pergunta "Node" é uma classe qualquer  criada por mim, eu só quero dizer pro typescript que se tiver algo ali, que seja uma instancia de "Node"